# How to find count in mongodb using $in and using greater than and lesser than?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have document in Test collection as given below:

```
{
    "_id" : "3233123123213123123",
    "sequence":30,
    "containIds":["fgx"]
}
{
    "_id" : "534545345345345345",
    "sequence":70,
    "containIds":["abc", "fgx"]
}
{
    "_id" : "56756676767676767",
    "sequence":160,
    "containIds":[]
}
db.getCollection('Test').find({"containIds":{$in: [ "fgx", "containIds" ]}}).count(); // result 1

and 

db.getCollection(Test').count({sequence:{ $gt :  0, $lt : 99}})//result 2
```

but i want to combine both query in one and need to get a result. //result should be 1

do i need to aggregate and project? how to write query for both using `$in` and (`$gt` and  `$lt`) in mongodb?

Comment: use `$facet` stage to separate both queries and use `$match` stage inside it to match your conditions and for count use `$count`

Comment: How to use $facet? if u dont mind can u share any example?

Comment: i have done using aggregate  ...db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $and: [{
            sequence : { $gt :  0, $lt : 99}
        }, {
            "containIds":{$in: [ "fgx", "containIds" ]}
        }]
    }
}]);...is that no issue with thi query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `aggregate()` method and `$facet` stage to separate both query and result,

- `first`, you can change the name, put your match criteria and `$count` to get total records
- `second`, you can change the name, put your match criteria and `$count` to get total records

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      first: [
        { $match: { "containIds": { $in: ["fgx", "containIds"] } } },
        { $count: "count" }
      ],
      second: [
        { $match: { sequence: { $gt: 0, $lt: 99 } } },
        { $count: "count" }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l5gH2BYBEsB)